# Customizing the order of loading of js files in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

Meteor loads all the file sets according to its own rule. Files from /lib then deeper paths bla bla.....

I want to create a atmosphere package which will override this by mentioning a list of files which will just load after all the packages loaded.

My package has to load last and mentioned files should load just after my package. Please suggest me some ways i could approach this. This is an approach to solve dependency issues.

Update: This question is invalid now since the Meteor is very mature than before. These problems are already solved by later version.

Comment: On StackOverflow you're supposed to make some effort in solving your problem before you post a question. A cursory Google search reveals [this blog post](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-package-only-app-structure-with-mediator-pattern), which explains exactly how to achieve what you're describing.

Comment: The only way you could accomplish this is to make everything in your app a package. Then using a "last" package you could add the rest in the order you want. Nevertheless, when you get used to how meteor loads the code and in fact keeps things cleaner. This might help
http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-package-only-app-structure-with-mediator-pattern

Comment: @GeoffreyBooth Well I did try and methodology in that blog would not be an efficient solution for my problem because i would have to make a    lot of packages in that case since my project is a bit huge. Now i use  numbering the file names to load them. Thank you.

Comment: @EricHauenstein i have tried adding the files into a package and load it... Well that obviously works but its not a good solution to my problem because and i have tried linking the files on project base folder which runs the files twice.

Comment: @phoenix thank you. but that is not an efficient solution to my problem..

Answer (score 2):

There is no a clear way to do this in your app as of yet (Meteor 0.8.x) but it is on the roadmap of Meteor Core: https://trello.com/c/mHK2dpr5/68-new-way-of-defining-packages-and-controlling-file-load-order.

In the meanwhile, it is good to know that you can easily define your load order in packages. So if you have some heavy reusable functionality in your app, you might want to extract it into a package. See https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-versioning-and-packages